# Unable to run parse dashboard

Tags: git, heroku, parse-platform, dashboard, parse-server

I got an error when trying to start the dashboard: 'parse-dashboard' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Before that, I have type the command 'npm install -g parse-dashboard' but could not help.

Comment: Did you try using sudo before npm installed? I know I had to for mine. Also may want to check if you have node properly installed as well. You can check this with:   'node -v'

Comment: My node is properly installed. When I type `node -v`, I got 'v4.3.2'. However, when I try using sudo, I got an error : 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command. @hybrdthry911

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sudo is a Unix specific command designed to allow a user to carry out administrative tasks with the appropriate permissions.

You could try it this way than the global install and see if that works. But you need to ensure that node and its dependencies are correctly installed.

1 – Clone parse-dashboard git repository

```
git clone https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard.git
```

2 – Run npm install
Once the repository has been cloned to your local machine, change directory (`cd`) into the ‘parse-dashboard’ directory

so, in the ‘parse-dashboard’ folder, run `npm install` at the Terminal. It could take a minute or three for the installation of all the Node packages to complete.

Comment: @Cyan can you maybe also share some light on your hosting setup?